# SQL - Categoria & Subcategoria

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma estrutura de categoria e subcategoria. E preciso listar todas as categorias, e posterior suas subcategorias... Mas na listagem deu errado. Estou usando o **codeigniter**.

Estrutura do Banco de Dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estrutura SQL:

```
SELECT c1.*,
       c2.id,
       c2.id_categoria,
       c2.categoria as nome_categoria
  FROM categoria AS c1
  LEFT JOIN categoria AS c2
    ON c2.id_categoria = c1.id
```

Como eu faço para listar todas as catgorias e subcategorias da forma correta? Dentro do mesmo SQL, pois farei a recuperação dos dados pelo foreach() para exibir todos as categorias e suas subcategorias. Hoje o resultado está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este deveria ser o resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A categoria saude deveria sair também no exemplo...

Comment: @rray tem alguma ideia? :)

Comment: Veja se isto serve para seu caso http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: Serviria sim, mas não conseguiria adaptar neste SQL

Comment: Por que não conseguiria adaptar ?

Comment: Não consegui compreender.. consegue postar um exemplo?

Comment: Andre veja se deste jeito serve http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b5c3e/3. Vou tentar fazer o do tutorial.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31484/discussion-between-devgaspa-and-andre-baill).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi bem, todas as categorias principais tem id_categoria = 0, então:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT c1.id,
            c1.categoria as categoria_principal,
            null as sub_categoria
    FROM categoria AS c1

    WHERE c1.id_categoria = 0

    UNION

    SELECT c2.id,
            c1.categoria as categoria_principal,
            c2.categoria as sub_categoria
    FROM categoria AS c1
      INNER JOIN categoria AS c2 ON c2.id_categoria = c1.id

    WHERE c1.id_categoria = 0
) as tbaux
ORDER BY categoria_principal, sub_categoria
```

Primeiro busca as categorias principais, depois as categorias principais mais as subcategorias

## Este é o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Simplificado:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN c2.id IS NULL
                THEN c1.id
                ELSE c2.id
            END AS id,
        c1.categoria as categoria_principal,
        c2.categoria as sub_categoria
FROM categoria AS c1
  LEFT JOIN categoria AS c2 ON c2.id_categoria = c1.id

WHERE c1.id_categoria = 0
ORDER BY categoria_principal, sub_categoria
```

Comment: É quase isso @Tiago Oliveira de Freita ....

Comment: Postei o resultado na sua questão, ali sobrou uma categoria...

Comment: Editei, pode testar novamente, até vou postar mais uma opção, dá para simplificar

Comment: Perfeito, isto mesmo. Agradeço demais!

Comment: Tem uma versão mais simples, deve funcionar também.

Comment: Na versão mais simples, faltou uma das categorias...

Comment: Estranho, então ignora (y)

Comment: De boa, funcionou a primeira e está OK! :) Muito thanks!